# How to run kubectl commands inside docker container cron job

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubectl, docker-container

1.kubectl commands giving response in container terminal and getting cluster-info.

```
[root@cronjob-cj-m1dr3tsda-aw5rv /]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://172.20.0.1:443
CoreDNS is running at https://172.20.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

2.We have crontab running inside container and scheduled some job in crontab as below

```
*/30 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/scheduler_job.sh >> /var/log/scheduler_job.log

cat scheduler_job.sh
#!/bin/bash
whereis kubectl
kubectl version --client
kubectl cluster-info
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
kubectl rollout restart ds/scheduler-ds -n kube-system

Above kubectl commands output is empty

kubectl: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
Tue Dec 20 11:05:04 UTC 2022
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.0", GitCommit:"b46a3f887ca979b1a5d14fd39cb1af43e7e5d12d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-12-08T19:58:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
```

Crontab scheduled job script have kubectl commands, Its giving output as blank, please help how can we configure to get cluster access to crontab scheduled job that running inside container?

Comment: Is that container running inside your cluster?

Comment: yes and crontab installed inside container

Comment: Can you explian better what you want to do and why you are not using default kubernetes jobs/Cronjobs? What should the job do with kubectl?

Comment: We need to do kubectl rollout restart some pods every 30 mins and we have separate cron file that added in container that can add more scheduler job in future...

Answer (score 0):

Your container to run a kubectl command cant use the default service account.
You need to create a specific one.

Here is a nice way to do that: https://itnext.io/running-kubectl-commands-from-within-a-pod-b303e8176088

But redeploying every 30 minutes sounds to me well known. If you get in memory or cpu issues, consider to add a resources section in sour deployment.

Something like so:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "1500m"
```

According to your needs also a livnessProbe, if you havent that already, can be a solution.

Comment: kubectl running on containers is working - issue with only cronjobs - here kubectl commands giving blank reponse, doesn't have access to cluster

Comment: Dont understand what you mean. You said your cronjobs are running inside the container.

Comment: I have updated question, hope that will clarify

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround available for this issue, you can try using [kubernetes jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) along with [kubernetes scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/) for executing your commands inside the pods at your desired time intervals or you can even trigger these jobs when a certain event happens.